# how do i reset the value of a single session array index in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Using a user model which returns an array that looks like this:

```
$user_data['display_name'] = "John Doe";

$user_data['avatar'] = ./images/user144.jpg";
```

i create my session using `$this->session->set_userdata('user_data',$user_data);`

now if on another controller i let the user change his avatar,

how can i replace the session variable associated to that?

like `$this->session->set_userdata('user_data["avatar"]',$new_avatar);`
just wont work right?

hee thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

From looking at an overview of your code, I'm guessing the best way to go about this is to unset the data and reset it.

Use $this->session->unset_userdata('thesessiontounset');
Then set it back up with the new information and old.

Answer (score 0):

The session->set_userdata() function will only let you modify one key at a time. In your case the key refers to an array so what you're trying to do isn't possible in the way you're attempting to do it.

When I'm updating my session I run something like this.

```
//Create or setup the array of the fields you want to update.
$newFields = array('avatar' = > 'image01.png');

//Check to see if the session is currently populated. 
if (!is_array($this->session->userdata('abc'))){
    //...and if it's not - set it to a blank array
    $this->session->set_userdata('abc',array());
}

//Retrieve the existing session data
$existing_session = $this->session->userdata('abc');

//Merge the existing data with the new data
$combined_data = array_merge($this->session->userdata('abc'), $newFields);
//update the session
$this->session->set_userdata('abc',$combined_data);
```

[More details on array_merge can be found here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 0):

First controller

```
$user_data['display_name'] = "John Doe";

$user_data['avatar'] = "./images/user144.jpg";

$this->session->set_userdata('user_data',$user_data);
```

Second controller

```
$user_data = $this->session->userdata('user_data');

$user_data['avatar'] = $new_avatar;

$this->session->set_userdata('user_data', $new_avatar);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late, but it might be useful to someone else, this seems to work:

```
$this->session->userdata['user_data']['avatar'] = $new_avatar;
$this->session->userdata['other_data']['other'] = $other;
$this->session->sess_write();
```

This allows you to edit values in array just like you do with `$_SESION['user_data']['avatar'] = $avatar`, with 'only' one extra line and only using CI library.

Answer (score 0):

For Unset Session variable

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('avatar');
```

For Set Session variable

```
$this->session->set_userdata('avatar', '/images/user144.jpg"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use just like this

```
$this->session->set_userdata('session_var',"");
```